# How to test methods passed in to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I've been struggling with trying to pin-point exactly how to resolve this problem, I have tried messing around with mock data and various different approaches and I'm still looking for solutions online.

I'm curious how I can set up my test so it detects the the true condition (CardTopic topic === "React") and then invoking the appropriate function.

Test

```
  it("should invoke renderReview if the local state topic equals 'React'", () => {
    wrapper = shallow(<CardTopic topic="React" />);
    wrapper.find("section").simulate("click");
    expect(wrapper.instance().handleClick).toEqual(renderReview);
  });
```

Error

```
TypeError: this.props.renderReview is not a function

      11 |   handleClick = () => {
      12 |     this.state.topic === "React"
    > 13 |       ? this.props.renderReview()
         |                    ^
      14 |       : this.props.renderNotFound();
      15 |   };
      16 |   render() {
```

Comment: You've got `topic` as a prop, so you probably want to move it to state.  How is `renderView` passed to `CardTopic`?  You need to simulate that too.

Comment: You seem to be sending in a prop `topic` but checking condition for `this.state.topic`, are they in sync somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple fix. You just need to supply your component with some [mock function](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api) `jest.fn()` props.

Please read more about: [describe](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#describename-fn) blocks, and [beforeEach](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#beforeeachfn-timeout) and [afterEach](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#aftereachfn-timeout) methods.

For example:

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme"
import CardTopic from '../path/to/CardTopic";

// jest mocked functions -- defined here for ease of use throughout the test
const renderReview = jest.fn(); 
const renderNotFound = jest.fn();

// define any initial props (this.props) the component uses   
const initialProps = {
  renderReview,
  renderNotFound,
  ...etc
}

describe("Card Topic", () => {

  let wrapper;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<CardTopic {...initialProps } />); // this resets wrapper for each test (removes any state that was set)
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    renderReview.mockClear(); // resets the mock information (number of times it's been called);
    renderNotFound.mockClear(); // resets the mock information (number of times it's been called);
    wrapper.unmount(); // unmounts each wrapper instance after each test 
  });

  it("renders renderReview if the local state topic equals 'React'", () => {
    wrapper.setState({ topic: "React" }); // set wrapper's "topic" state
    wrapper.update(); // update the wrapper with this new state

    wrapper.instance().handleClick(); // invoke the method

    expect(renderReview).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // expect a mock function to be called
    expect(renderNotFound).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0); // not needed, but here for declarative purposes
  });

  it("renders renderNotFound if the local state topic does not equal 'React'", () => {
    wrapper.setState({ topic: "Redux" }); // set wrapper's "topic" state
    wrapper.update(); // update the wrapper with this new state

    wrapper.instance().handleClick(); // invoke the method

    expect(renderNotFound).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // expect a mock function to be called
    expect(renderReview).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0); // not needed, but here for declarative purposes
  });
});
```

---

If you don't want to use mock functions but want to test against the actual functions, then you'll need to import those functions and supply them the same way as demonstrated above. Then, if those functions alter the `DOM`, then you'll need to make assertions against the `DOM`.